# "I do can..." - is this valid (even informally)?

Tags: informal-language

While talking to my daughter yesterday, I challenged her that she *cannot* get ready in 10 minutes. We were, actually, going out. She's keen in learning English, and she surprises me with either her answers or her questions!

Now the general case:

We emphasize our confidence by putting **do (verb)** as in...

> You don't see that ~ Ah, I ***do see!*** 
>  You don't care ~ I ***do care!***

But, the conversation went like:

> Rhyme, leave it! You cannot get ready in 10 minutes 
>  Dad, I ***do can!***

Now, grammatically, it could be plain wrong. I know this. But, my question is by any chance, **even in an informal language** ...is it correct?

Comment: *"I sure can"* sounds meaningful.

Comment: @CinCout aww... I ***surely*** can!

Comment: Am I wrong in using *sure*? AFAIK, it is just an informal way while *surely* is formal.

Comment: @CinCount: you're right - *surely* is formally correct but *sure* is in common colloquial use.

Answer (score 2):

"I can do." is a common enough expression or even just "Can do."

As for "I do can." -- Sorry, no can do.  That doesn't work at any degree of informality.

Comment: Indeed, I can't think of any occasion where "do" can come before a modal (we can't say *"do shall", *"do will", *"do may", *"do must", *"do might"*) even in the most informal language (although "did ought" is acceptable as a replacement for "ought not", and "did use(d) to" always works informally, but those are semi-modals).  Some dialects permit modal-stacking, e.g. "might should", but I've never seen "do can" (though "do" is non-modal anyway), but even if it exists in some dialect, it would definitely be nonstandard.

Comment: As a native US English speaker, I've never heard anyone say "I can do", and it sounds very weird to me.  "Can do", yes, but not "**I** can do."  Can you provide any source or reference for it?

Comment: "I can do" is perfectly normal in BrE (although it's no more emphatic than "I can", so it isn't comparable to the non-existent "I do can" form).  See https://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.co.uk/2007/09/pro-predicate-do-and-verb-phrase.html